# The Connection with the server was reset

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am getting the following error while downloading the documents from the document library. Even if the file is small in size.

1. In my dev environment it is working fine. Even the QA and PRD also working fine in my Dev environment
   I am using IE11 Server2008 R2 OS.
2. My client is using a laptop having windows 7 OS and IE8.
   In my client system the dev url is working fine and he can able to download the documents from the document library. But from QA and PRD he is unable to download the documents. While downloading the documents from QA or PRD environments, he is getting the following error. I tried these urls in Chrome browser also. It shows network error.

Please suggest me what thing i need to modify to get these documents.

Thanks
Kishore Reddy

Comment: what authentication you are using? what is browser handling setting for web app? is the url of the site is in Trusted zone?